# What type of fish is this

Tags: species-identification, ichthyology

I saw this fish in an aquarium in a nearby house .I am not sure which species and sex this fish belongs to.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOAZx.jpg[image]

Comment: looks like a listless guppy or a platy. note the upwards pointed mouth, that is a fish that swims around most of the time and is adapted to surface feeding, they rarely stay still at the bottom. use rainwater and give them rocks and plants and they will sink less. https://www.google.com/search?q=sunset+platy&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicoIK_no_kAhVJSxoKHV5yABIQ_AUIESgB&biw=1972&bih=1070#imgrc=9IXX4HlKwHCbXM:

Comment: I thought it was a gold panda molly. It looked like below [imagehttps://images.app.goo.gl/uMoAfH3o5RpF1hRk6]

Comment: Your picture is unclear. Can you please post a better image?